# Adding new contact to iMessage group chat

Tags: messages

With iMessage there is a group chat feature similar to the feature in Whats App. But I can't find a way to add new people to an ongoing group chat.

Is this possible?

Comment: There seems to be no ability to add/edit the recipient of an iMessage/SMS text. You can select Edit and then Forward all or parts of an ongoing message to others, but there is no context (who said what).

Comment: i believe you have to wait for iOS 8

Answer (score 1):

No. Its not possible, though its nice feature to add to in next version.

Comment: Does anyone know if this feature (add/remove to/from group text) will be in the next upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible in Yosemite: just click "Add Contact…" in the Details pane.

Answer (score -2):

You can, go create new message then where it says recipients (or to:) add as many people (On imessage) as you like.

Comment: That unfortunately only works for new group messages, not to extend existing ones (which is what the asker is looking for).